# jQuery paradigm?

Tags: jquery, oop, methodology, paradigms

It seems to me that jQuery doesn't seem to be written as an OOP framework, it seems too short, and not verbose enough for that.  Am I right in thinking this and if it isn't written as OOP, then what methodology/paradigm are they using?

Comment: If you wish a javascript framework which takes the OOP approach try Dojo or Prototype.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

They use the **functional programming** paradigm.

It's tiny, it's straightforward, and it's fast.

Comment: jQuery often relies on state and mutable data, which is contrary to most definitions of functional programming.

Answer (score 9):

I would suspect the methodology to be: **make it as small and as fast as possible.**

Comment: ...and yet modularized. Sure, not in a very OOP-way, but mainly because JavaScript is not object oriented.

Comment: @Felix, I would say javascript is object oriented. But it depends a little bit of how you define oo.

Comment: JavaScript is object oriented language... but it's prototype based OO, not class based OO.

Comment: Hmm, I remember reading somewhere JavaScript was not OO. However, it seems Wikipedia says it's OO. Oh well, terminologies *sigh*

Answer (score 3):

jQuery behaves like a [monad](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monad_(functional_programming)). Monads are usually used in functional programming langauges such as Haskell, but are not limited to them. See http://importantshock.wordpress.com/2009/01/18/jquery-is-a-monad/

I'm reluctant to say jQuery uses the functional programming paradigm because it is very stateful, which functional programs try to avoid.

Answer (score 2):

No, jquery isn't written to be a oo framework. It is all about abstracting the dom and ajax. Here is a great article about the differences between jquery and mootools: http://jqueryvsmootools.com/